# jquerymobile ui-page width panel listview

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm making a mobile site using jquery-mobile and have tried to set up the desktop version to look the same by fixing the width of the ui-page in the css for desktop.

This seems to work correctly except that I can no longer click on the listview entries in my overlay panel menu. If I hover my cursor over the links it doesn't change the cursor over a link as you would expect. And clicking just makes the panel disappear again. This works fine without the ui-page width css additions but I can't see why.

Is there anything obvious I've not considered?

My css is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .ui-page {
        width: 800px !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
       position: relative !important;
    }
}
```

and the html for the panel is

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-page">

<div data-role="panel" id="mainMenu" data-theme="b" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-animate="false">
    <ul data-role="list-view" class="ui-listview ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <li>
            <h3>200 Solemn Faces</h3>
        </li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="archive.php">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://www.zazzle.com/hahapeculiar" target="_blank">Merchandise</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider"><h3>Support</h3></li>
        <li>(this includes upvoting, sharing, and also of course Patreon)</li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="support.php" target="_blank">How to support</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://patreon.com/hahapeculiar" target="_blank">Patreon</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://topwebcomics.com/members/votefavorite.aspx?id=19543" target="_blank">Vote on TopWebComics</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider"><h3>Follow</h3></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://twitter.com/solemn_faces" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://www.facebook.com/hahapeculiar" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://plus.google.com/109016014274913676934" target="_blank">Google+</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://tapastic.com/series/hahapeculiar" target="_blank">Tapastic</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="http://eepurl.com/bpz8C1" target="_blank">Mailing List</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="/rss.xml" target="_blank">RSS Feed</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My page as it stands at the moment is [here](http://solemnfaces.whaymand.com), with the button at the top-right making the panel in question appear

Comment: Messing with `ui-page` properties changes the behaviour/position of `ui-panel-dismiss` in some way. Try another approach to change page size